# Выборка значений из mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос на php к mySQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT  dateblock FROM users";
```

Как сделать в запросе, чтобы выбирались данные razreshenie =1 если dateblock >= чем текущая дата и равнялись 0, если меньше ?

В итоге должна получиться такая таблица

```
             razreshenie   datablock

строка 1        1         10-02-2018

строка 2        0         01-01-2018

строка 3        0         03-01-2018

строка 4        0         02-01-2018

строка 5        1         25-02-2018
```

Comment: выбираются все строки...только значение разрешение меняется в зависимости от значения даты ...where сразу ограничит количество строк...это не то..

Comment: Условия в MySQL как раз возвращают 0 или 1 ... так что `select dateblock, (dateblock >= NOW()) as razreshenie` даст как раз требуемое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
SELECT  dateblock,(DATE(dateblock)>=DATE(NOW())) as razreshenie FROM users
```

Вариант 2:

```
SELECT  dateblock,IF(DATE(dateblock)>=DATE(NOW()),'true','false') as razreshenie FROM users
```

Вместо `true` и `false` можно написать 1 и 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  dateblock 
FROM users 
WHERE (razreshenie =1 AND dateblock >=NOW()) 
OR (razreshenie =0 AND dateblock < NOW())
```